# Getting a "Command cex was not found" error trying to execute "drush cex"

Tags: windows-10, git-bash, drupal

I've installed Drush for my Drupal website on Windows 10 and I'm trying to export the config settings using `drush cex` in Git Bash.

However, when doing this I get the following error:

> Command cex was not found. Drush was unable to query the database. As a result, many commands are unavailable. Re-run your command with --debug to see relevant log messages.

I feel like the problem might be in the fact that my user folder is called `Tom Lastname` and thus has a space in it. This at least results in error messages for `cd` and other commands.

`which drush` yields the right folder so it is correctly installed. However, there is no `drush.php` there. Only `drush` and `drush.bat`.

The complete error message I get using `drush cex --debug` is shown in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of error message for drush cex --debug]

Answer (score 0):

The command `drush cex` seems to need to use `mysql`. 
Did you notice the error

```
  'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
```

about 40% of the way down your screenshot? 
You need to add `msyql` to your search path —
see [drush-ops/drush · Issue #3464](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/3464) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott that worked! I installed MySQL and added it to my path. However, I had already MySQL through XAMPP and thus have the two instances now it seems like although there is only one in Program Files. Would this not give conflictions? Sorry, quite new to all this.

Comment: Well, I’m not familiar with ``drush``, but it seems to me that, if you already had ``mysql`` on your system,  you should have just added it to your path, and not installed a second copy.